# How to display only part of a string using PHP/html/java?

Tags: php, string

Usernames on my website are all stored in a form like this "steve.jones" or "lisa-ann.smith", and referred to in my code as only $login (string).

Is there any way i can display only the first name on a site, and changing the first letter to capital?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, you can use the explode function delimited by ".", and then use the ucfirst function to convert the same to first letter uppercase

```
<?php
$login = "steve.jones";
$firstname = explode(".", $login);
$firstname[0] = ucfirst($firstname[0]);
echo $firstname[0];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like just the beginning of the word you can use the explode function. See Doc here:http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$login = "steve.jones";
```

Explode function breaks up the string at the delimiter you set. In this case it's a full stop. This breaks the string into separate words each available at an index. Returns an `array`

```
$names = explode(".", $login);
```

The first index gets the first part of the string in this case it's steve

```
echo $name[0]; // steve
```

`ucfirst` makes the first letter a capital letter. See Doc here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php

```
 echo ucfirst($name[0]); // Steve
```

To use this in your code, you can store the result in a new variable or re-write to the existing variable. The complete solution will look like:

```
$login = "steve.jones";
$names = explode(".", $login);
$forename = ucfirst($names[0]); // Steve
```

Answer (score 0):

- [[php doc]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) use strpos() to find the `.`
- [[php doc]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) substr() to get string till the position get from the strpos().
- [[php doc]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) use ucfirst() to make the first letter capital.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:- Try something before ask**

### Splitting a string by a regular expression

see documentation:- [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

> array preg_split ( string $pattern , string $subject [, int $limit =
>   -1 [, int $flags = 0 ]] )

**Change case of the first letter.**

see documentation:- [ucfirst](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php)

> string ucfirst ( string $str )

**combining them**

```
// Spliting with '-' and '.'
$splited = preg_split('/([\.\-])/',$string);
// Cahnge casing
$firstname = ucfirst($splited[0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try explode by '.' + ucfirst